# Need to get current location and destination location pin

Tags: iphone

How do I get the current location with green pin and destination location with red pin?

When I work on some stuff I get only destination location with red pin, not at the current location.

My source code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    NSString *mTitle;
    NSString *mSubTitle;

//  CLLocationManager *locationManager;
//  CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
@end
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>  {

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;    
    AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation;
    NSString *address;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
+(MapViewController *)sharedInstance;
-(void)start;
-(void)stop;
-(BOOL)locationKnown;
@property(nonatomic,retain)CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *address;
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation;
-(void)showAddress;
@end


#import "MapViewController.h"

@implementation AddressAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;
//@synthesize currentLocation;

- (NSString *)subtitle{
    //return @"Sub Title";
    return @"Event";
}
- (NSString *)title{
    //return @"Title";
    return @"Allure-Exclusive";
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    coordinate=c;
    //NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude);
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize address;
@synthesize currentLocation;

static MapViewController *sharedInstance;

+(MapViewController *)sharedInstance{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if (!sharedInstance) 
        [[MapViewController alloc]init];
        }
    return sharedInstance;
}
+(id)alloc{
    @synchronized(self){
        NSAssert(sharedInstance==nil,"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton LocationController."); 
        sharedInstance = [super alloc];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(id)init{
    if(self==[super init]){
        self.currentLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]init];
        locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        locationManager.delegate=self;
        [self start];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)start{
    NSLog(@"Start");
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)stop{
    mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
-(BOOL)locationKnown{
    if (round(currentLocation.speed)==-1) 
        return NO;
        else return YES;

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]])<120){
        self.currentLocation=newLocation;
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} 
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"Map-View";
//  [self addressLocation];
    [self showAddress];
    NSLog(@"address is %@",address);

}

-(void)showAddress{ 

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.5;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.5;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;

    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [addAnnotation release];
        addAnnotation = nil;
    }

    addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];

}


-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 

   [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"locationString %@",locationString);
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"listItems %@",[listItems objectAtIndex:2]);
    }
    else {
        //Show error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    if (annotation==mapView.userLocation) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        annView.animatesDrop=YES;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
        return annView;
            //
}
    else {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop=YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}



}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
//  [self stop];
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [address release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if (annotation==mapView.userLocation)
    {
    mapView.userLocation.title=@"Current Location";
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000)animated:YES];
    return nil;
}
else {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop=YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;

}
}
```

When I changed the method. it's pointing blue and blinking,but it was pointing at different location, which is at infinite Loop mariani Ave location.

It was running this in a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set showsUserLocation.

`mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Comment: I set that in viewdidload mapview.showsuserlocation=yes;  but its not showing sir.